# In Android RelativeLayout maxWidth doesn't work

Tags: android, layout

I got `RelativeLayout` in content:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:
    android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxWidth="350dp"
    ></RelativeLayout>
```

`android:maxWidth="350dp"` doesn't work. With `wrap_content` for `layout_width` and `layout_height` neither works `.

Comment: Please share screenshot for same what you exactly want?

Comment: You got `android:layout_width="match_parent"` that means your layout will be as alrge in width as it's possible

Comment: @A.Shevchuk I changed it for `wrap_content` but its the same.

Comment: @Januszj., can you clarify what is expected result for you?

Comment: Is your RelativeLayout a child of LinearLayout?

Comment: @A.Shevchuk I want to set max width of it thats all.

Comment: @WadeWilson Its Main Layout

Comment: I believe that was you problem using layout_weight=''1" and layout_width="0". layout_weight is an attribute of LinearLayout and therefor only it's children can use it. Try nesting inside of a LinearLayout and setting those fields.

Comment: @WadeWilson Nesting empty layouts is bad practise. The problem is not with `weight` but with set `maxWidth` and  with `RelativeLayout` that inherits `maxWidth` object from ViewGroup class.

Comment: I just checked the documentation for RelativeLayout or even ViewGroupp and their isn't an attribute for android:maxWidth. It's been declared per View and not all, so for example the  Views EditText and ContraintLayout all have that attribute.

Comment: @WadeWilson you are right.

Comment: I'll add an answer because I've seen this question before and no one has come out and explicitly mentioned that the attribute isn't available to all Views.

Comment: @WadeWilson not all Views, for some it is available (TextView etc.), not even for all `ViewGroups` from documentation [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for RelativeLayout and even ViewGroup doesn't mention an attribute for android:maxWidth. This attribute, as well maxHeight, are instead declared per View, inside of the attrs.xml file of the Android SDK. So, for example the Views [TextView, EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxWidth), [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:maxWidth) and [ContraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html), all have that attribute, but Spinner does not. You have to implement complex layouts, create custom ViewGroups that support maxWidth/maxHeight or use multiple layout files with dimension modifiers to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that `maxWidth` param for `RelativeLayout` couldn't and can't work. But  it's not recognized as wrong parameter for `RelativeLayout` by Android Studio UI. `Maxwidth` param is available for `Views` and `ConstraintLayout` so in the solution I will add `relative positioning` to `ConstraintLayout` with this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) .